# We still can’t sleep. / We can’t sleep yet

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I asked about these two sentences in another forum sometime ago and I've been told the following possible meanings:

1. We still can't sleep. - We've been trying to go to sleep, but we are unable to fall asleep.
2. We can't sleep yet. - We still have things to do, so we can't go to sleep now.

Now it seems "we can't sleep yet" means the same thing as "we can't go to bed yet". But aren't sleeping and going to bed different? Can the second sentence mean "we can't fall asleep yet"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically, it can, of course. With a little imagination you can probably think of a scenario where someone is in bed but doesn't want to go to sleep yet, or maybe it's night but they need to keep watch so must not fall asleep.

Comment: Yes. We don't 'go to bed' just to sleep, and we don't only sleep in a bed.

Comment: Thank you for your help!